# How to make a python request, load javascript, fill in the form and click submit

Tags: python, python-2.7

So there is a page with the following contents;

```
<input type="text" name="input1">
<input type="text" name="input2">
<button onclick="dosomething()" id="check">Check</button>
```

This page gets loaded in with javascript, so you need to wait until it's fully loaded. After that the text files has to be filled in, and click the submit button. If it succeeds, it will set a cookie and redirect you. If it doesn't succeeds, it doesn't do anything.

How can I make this work in python? I couldn't really find a answer that would work for me. This python code will be runned in Windows.

Comment: I am not sure what you want to do here. Do you want to click on the link/submit using python or you just want to submit your file using python script?

Comment: @AviralVerma I want to go to the url. Wait until it's fully loaded. Then submit with the input tags filled in.

Comment: $(document).ready(function() { afterLoadDoSomething() });

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you could just send direct request with form's field. Based on form's method it'll be GET or POST request. Later you can catch and save coockies and head to redirected page. 
If it doesn't work you could also try Selenium to emulate user's behaviour